# How do I bring an unmanaged application window to front, and make it the active window for (simulated) user input

Tags: c#, windows, pinvoke, foreground

I am assuming I need to use pinvoke but I am not sure which function calls are needed.

Scenario: a legacy application will be running, I will have Handle for that application.

I need to:

1. bring that application to the top (in front of all other windows)
2. make it the active window

Which Windows function calls are needed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you don't have a handle to the window, use this before :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
```

Now assuming you have a handle to the application window :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

This will make the taskbar flash if another window has keyboard focus.

If you want to force the window to come to the front, use [ForceForegroundWindow](http://pastebin.com/zkdZvKuG) (sample implementation).

Comment: SetForegroundWindow seems to do what I need so far however I get error when trying to call ForceForegroundWindow ("Unable to find an entry point named 'ForceForegroundWindow' in DLL 'user32.dll'.")

Comment: In my case, I had to use 'BringWindowToTop' in addition to this. ForceForegroundWindow solved my problem beautifully. Thanks!

Comment: Is this the ForceForegroundWindow code you mentioned: http://pastebin.com/zkdZvKuG ?

Comment: @user1681490 Sadly I don't remember what the original code was, but it's possible, yes.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae how would I include/use the WinAPI class in C#?

Comment: For what it's worth, I found the ForceForegroundWindow full example here: https://shlomio.wordpress.com/2012/09/04/solved-setforegroundwindow-win32-api-not-always-works/ via http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetForegroundWindow.html I can't seem to get it to work in Win 10 v1903, but it could just be the application I'm working to bring forward.

Answer (score 16):

This has proved to be extremely reliable. The ShowWindowAsync function is specifically designed for windows created by a different thread. The SW_SHOWDEFAULT makes sure the window is *restored* prior to showing, then activating.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr windowHandle, int nCmdShow);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr windowHandle);
```

Then making the calls:

```
ShowWindowAsync(windowHandle, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
ShowWindowAsync(windowHandle, SW_SHOW);
SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle);
```

Comment: Works like a charm while every other code I tried failed.

Comment: This has worked great in Windows 11 as well, also after trying lots of different things.

Answer (score 12):

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(HandleRef hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr WindowHandle);
    public const int SW_RESTORE = 9;
```

ShowWindowAsync method is used to show the minimized application and SetForegroundWindow method is used to bring on front the back application.

you can use these methods as i used in my application to bring the skype infront of my application. on button click

```
private void FocusSkype()
    {
        Process[] objProcesses = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("skype");
        if (objProcesses.Length > 0)
        {
            IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
            hWnd = objProcesses[0].MainWindowHandle;
            ShowWindowAsync(new HandleRef(null,hWnd), SW_RESTORE);
             SetForegroundWindow(objProcesses[0].MainWindowHandle);
        }
    }
```