# Find windows on application from another desktop

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7

I have same user logged in into windows 7 station with several simultaneous sessions (like Concurrent RDP or log in at station and then via RDP).

**UPDATE:**
Ok, my research in this question has been stuck at this point (python example to write less complicated code):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes as wintypes
def enum_desktops():
    GetProcessWindowStation = user32.GetProcessWindowStation

    EnumDesktops = user32.EnumDesktopsW
    EnumDesktopsProc = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(wintypes.BOOL, wintypes.LPWSTR, wintypes.LPARAM)
    hwinsta = GetProcessWindowStation()

    def foreach_desktop(desk_name, lparam):
        print("Desktop %s"%desk_name)
        return True
    EnumDesktops(hwinsta, EnumDesktopsProc(foreach_desktop), desk_lparam)
```

This function prints information about "Default" and "Winlogon" dektops. If we try to enumerate window stations, we'll get **only** "WinSta0", while I can see potentially target process started on different logon session.

So, what should I use to find window for target Desktop?

daemon is not an option at this point at all.

Comment: If there's really no way or it's too complicated, I'll start daemon on every desktop to get control over windows.

Comment: What do you mean simultaneous sessions? You mean of a specific applications or multiple same-user interactive sessions.

Comment: Concurrent RDP, like for server software

Comment: I can't think of any great way to do this. You could implement logon scripts to write to a share for logons, and then clear it nightly / on logoff. Maybe scrape through events on the clients for open RDP sessions... Nothing real clean that I can think of, unless there is some terminal server or similar software that you could use instead of bare RDP.

Comment: What are you really trying to do by enumerating windows from a different desktop session? What are you trying to achieve by doing this. I ask because there may be a better way.

Comment: @selbie, I need to ensure user application's window is active at the moment and activate if it is not active. I can't check this in another way.

Comment: @AthomSfere, it's impossible in this particular case. I need to run monitor by user himself.

Comment: Is the active window you want to check an application you wrote? Or just some generic tool / app?

Comment: @AthomSfere no, I don't develop this application and hacking it in any way is not an option.

Comment: @selbie, can you tell me what do you want to share for this question.

Comment: I am still a little confused on what your trying to do, is this the general direction you are heading?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228089/how-do-i-bring-an-unmanaged-application-window-to-front-and-make-it-the-active

Comment: Calls like FindWindow, EnumWindows and many others uses windows only from current desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Have a background app or task tray applet that gets launched with every desktop session. (Easily installed by adding an EXE path to the following registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Run).

The code that lives in that installed application will do two things:

1. All the desktop windows enumeration and manipulation that you need to do that can only interact with the local desktop.
2. Acts as a "Client" to your "server" app that runs on another desktop session. Your server app is what triggers the clients to do the window scanning.  You can use almost any interprocess communication mechanism you want for this.

Comment: As I have comment myself in first option.

Comment: The worst thing in this client-server is there no way to make scripting support easily.

Comment: @EirNym - There's nothing easy about what you are trying to achieve. As such, you are going to have to do some hard (but not impossible) work to make this happen. I'm not sure why you knocked my answer for lack of scripting support, as you never mentioned it in your original question. You seem deliberately vague on what you are trying to do, as such, you may not get the best answers.

Comment: The client/server idea is just an idea. You can easily add "scripting" to it by having the server push a script file to the clients and have the clients run it.

Comment: I see. But I have to write much more code to move it to trash later at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Already some time passed from the time the question was posted, but in case someone needs it, I will post an answer.

What you have to do is set a desktop for your current thread, which is calling `FindWindow`. In this way, your calling thread will operate in other desktop and will find a window. For this to achieve, you have to use `SetThreadDesktop` WinAPI function.

For more info, check MSDN documentation on [SetThreadDesktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686250(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @Eirnym, don't forget to spawn a different thread, on which you will call ````SetThreadDesktop````. Otherwise, if you call it from ````MainThread````, it won't work.