# Mutex kills application

Tags: c#, mutex

This is my code:

```
protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // Used to check if we can create a new mutex
        bool newMutexCreated = false;

        try
        {
            // Create a new mutex object with a unique name
            mutex = new Mutex(false, MutexName, out newMutexCreated);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
            when (ex is UnauthorizedAccessException ||
                ex is IOException ||
                ex is WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException ||
                ex is ArgumentException)
        {
            Logger.Error("Error while launching application. Failed to check for other instances.", ex);
            Shutdown((int)ExitCode.ApplicationAlreadyRunning);
        }

        // When the mutex is created for the first time
        // we run the program since it is the first instance.
        if (newMutexCreated)
        {
            await ContinueStartup(e);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise we get the first instance with that process name,
            Process[] currentProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(AssemblyName);
            IntPtr mainWindowHandle = currentProcesses[0].MainWindowHandle;
            if (mainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                // maximize it, if it was minimized, and set it to foreground.
                Logger.Info("Another instance of the application is already running.");
                ShowWindow(mainWindowHandle, WindowShowNormal);
                SetForegroundWindow(mainWindowHandle);
            }

            // Then shutdown this instance.
            Logger.Info("Shutting down.");
            Shutdown((int)ConsoleModeExitCode.ApplicationAlreadyRunning);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        Logger.Info("Exiting application.");

        // Close mutex.
        mutex.Dispose();

        base.OnExit(e);
    }
```

What happens here is that my application should start once. While it is running, every attempt to start a new instance should bring the first instance to the front.

But what actually happens is: after 2-10 launch-attempts the first instance's GUI is killed, the process is still running and blocking the Mutex and can only be killed in the TaskManager. If I try to debug this behaviour and run the application in VisualStudio, it just never happens. Trying to open the application 50 times never kills it, so I can't follow the events that seem to occur.

Is it normal behaviour of the GarbageCollector? It kills the first instance in case it is hanging?
Or am I missing something?

Comment: what do you mean "the first instance's GUI is killed"? what exactly happens?

Comment: Why do you think this has something to do with the mutex? What does "killed" mean? Do you get an exception? Does the process continue to run? Also `Process.MainWindowHandle` isn't very useful - are you sure you're getting a valid handle, and using it in the proper way (you're using P/Invokes, so it's quite possible you're breaking things in an ugly way)? Have you checked the return values? Have you read the docs for `ShowWindow` and `SetForegroundWindow` thoroughly?

Comment: I mean the application is opened, I have an instance on the TaskBar and can click it and work with it. And then I try to open an instance as a process from another application, this code is executed in the 2nd instance and then the first instance disappears from TaskBar and only stays in the TaskManager as process, blocking new Mutexes.

Comment: Okay, @Luaan might have the point. Commenting those both lines (ShowWindow & SetForeground) stops the killing. I gotta fix this instead (or at least try/catch). Googling for mutex gave me thousands of "mutex is dangerous", "using mutex RIGHT" and stuff. So I was sure I'm using my mutex wrong. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as @Luaan mentioned the problem was not the Mutex.
I fixed my code with this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9059657/3319147

`ShowWindowAsync` and a slightly different handling of the IntPtr-value of the handle seems to make this *way more* stable. Couldn't crash it since. For me this is enough stability :)