# Bring another application into foreground when WPF XAML window is in Maximized

Tags: c#, wpf, office-interop

I have a WPF application in which the main window is set to full screen via `WindowState="Maximized"` in the `Window` tag. In the application, I'm opening PowerPoint through the Office Interop libraries with the intention that PowerPoint opens in the foreground, on top of the WPF application. However, PowerPoint is not consistently coming to the foreground (particularly on Windows 7 machines). In these cases I have to press the Windows key to bring up the Windows Taskbar and click on the PowerPoint icon.

I've tried a few things, such as using `SetForegroundWindow()` from the Win32 API, the `.Activate()` function in the PowerPoint Interop library, and the `AutomationElement` class (here's some code for the last one):

```
Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("POWERPNT").FirstOrDefault();
AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);

if (element != null)
{
    element.SetFocus();
}
```

However, none of these seem to consistently bring PowerPoint to the front. Does anyone know why exactly this behavior is occurring and how best to get PowerPoint into the foreground?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228089/how-do-i-bring-an-unmanaged-application-window-to-front-and-make-it-the-active

Comment: I've seen that answer and used the `SetForegroundWindow()` function, but unfortunately that didn't seem to work. Seems to work when the `WindowState` is not set to `Maximized` though.

Answer (score 0):

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(HandleRef hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr WindowHandle);

    public const int SW_RESTORE = 9;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("POWERPNT").FirstOrDefault();
        IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
        hWnd = process.MainWindowHandle;
        ShowWindowAsync(new HandleRef(null, hWnd), SW_RESTORE);
        SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
    }
```

works fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

This may work in your case:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.AppActivate("fullTitleOfWindow_OR_firstLettersOfWindowTitle");
```