# How to bring a HTA window hidden by another Windows window to the front?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, hta

I am launching a HTA file via Process.Start() in a COM surrogate process.

For some reason, the process starts in a maximized window which is immediately hidden by the application window creating it.

How can I put this HTA window to the front? I have tried SetWindowPos etc with no success.

This does work for Notepad, but not for the HTA

This would work for launching Notepad

```
private static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
private const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
private const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
private const UInt32 TOPMOST_FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE;
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

....
Process p = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
Thread.Sleep(500); // Allow the process to open it's window

SetWindowPos(p.MainWindowHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);
```

Comment: is the window actually hidden or just behind...

Comment: It's behind and since it's a HTA the window has in the taskbar's right click menu only Close button, not Minimize, Maximize, anything.

Comment: And the app that launched it isnt set to always be on top?

Comment: No. The problem is that the HTA is launched in a COM Surrogate.

Comment: and if I click on Taskbar, the app goes to the foreground. If I press ALT+TAB, the app goes to the foreground. So I was thinking I should be somehow able to emulate those calls, but no success yet.

Comment: Have you tried `SetForegroundWindow`?

Comment: yes, does not work.

Comment: How did you try the setforgroundwindow cos it should work

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228089/how-do-i-bring-an-unmanaged-application-window-to-front-and-make-it-the-active there is a FORCE bring it to front

Comment: The problem with SetForegroundWindow is the handle you pass into. There is something special about the HTA window launched from COM surrogate which escapes me. 

You launch the hta as Process.Start("myapp.hta") and then neither the handle of this process nor of the FindWindow by title works.

Comment: You do understand, that `Process.Handle` returns a process handle. That's a *very* different animal from a window handle. Anyway, please show a [mcve].

Comment: I actually used all kinds of handles I came across, including  Process.MainWindowHandle which does work for Notepad.exe. 

Unfortunately, I cannot share the example since it's proprietary code. 

I will see if I can simplify and share.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is surprisingly simple

```
                var thread = new Thread(() => {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(500);

                        var me = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
                        var myProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(me.ProcessName);
                        foreach (var p in myProcesses)
                        {
                            if (p.Id != me.Id)
                            {
                                SwitchToThisWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, true);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.Exception(e);
                    }});

                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                thread.Start();
```

....

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern void SwitchToThisWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool fAltTab);
```